# Where to put mod­erncv class package after downloading it in Windows 7?

Tags: miktex, installing, moderncv, windows, ctan

I got an error that moderncv.cls is missing. So, I have downloaded the complete package from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/?lang=en) . But I don't understand where should I place it so that I won't get this error.

Comment: You should install it with the package manager from your distribution.

Comment: How can I do it? I am using Windows-7 and using TexMaker as my editor.

Comment: Is your distribution MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: @ Bernard: MikTex

Comment: @Bernard: basic MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit installer

Comment: Then use the MikTeX package manager. You can find it in the MikTeX menu in the start menu. It has nothing to do with TeXMaker!

Comment: @daleif: I tried to use it as suggested in the answer below but I am getting an error while downloading. My internet is working fine. I have manually downloaded the files but I don't know where shall I put them.

Answer (score 1):

From `Start menu > All Programs > MiKTeX 2.9 > Maintenance (Administrator)`, launch `MiKTeX Package Manager`, rightclick on `moderncv` and select `Install`. That's all.

[image]

Comment: though the internet connection is working and is quite fast still I am getting an error `MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Data: connect failed in tcp_connect()`                       Is there any way that I can manually put the modercv package which I have downloaded?

Comment: You can change Package Repository from the `Repository` menu in MPM.

Comment: I tried to do it but there is nothing much which there which can be done.

Comment: Don't you have a bunch of mirrors listed?

Comment: no..I don't have it. I just downlaoded the .exe file and installed it

Comment: I' feel like we don't speak of the same thing. Did you launch `MiKTeX Package Manager (Administrator)`?

Comment: Yes, I have followed exactly the same steps for which you have provided a screenshot. But with that method, I was getting an download error which I have mentioned above. I also tried to change the repository but I don't have the packages in DVD/CD form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25491/discussion-between-bernard-and-skm).